# install issue with nvidia drivers and low resolution

Tags: nvidia, install

so i tried out elementary for the first time on my main PC as i have been really liking what the team has been doing. I elected to install third part drivers upon install, and when it loaded i saw that the nvidia drivers were there, however i could not get a normal screen res. it listed only a 720x 640 or something, not 1080 or 2k to match my screen. im not having any black screen issues or the tearing/flashing reported in other posts. Just stuck at low res

i tried a few things including adding some other PPAs, but nothing would let me change the resolution.

system is an i5 8600k with GTX 1080
Any thoughts?